# Display X characters after matched word

Tags: grep

I'd like to display the file and version number for different services. For example there might be a line in the text file that says `nginx 1.13.0`. I'd like to be able to search every single instance of `nginx [0-9].[0-9].[0-9]` and have it displayed with the version number and file name / line.

I've already tried this command which works well for displaying the matched files:

```
grep -lrEH "nginx [0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, missing that it might be more than one digit `+`. You should also escape the `.`, so it mean only `.` and not any character.

Try:

```
grep -EHro "nginx [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

Comment: I'm looking to have it output the filename and the version number of the nginx server. For example /out/www.host.com/hashfile - nginx 0.0.2

Comment: @JacobCross Try updated solution.  `-l` changed to `-o`